# Is there any R function or scripts to interchange the choice value in the following choice set data?

Tags: r, function, scripting, dplyr, case-when

dataset: mode=c(taxi, taxi, taxi, taxi), choice = c(1, 0, 0, 0), mainmode = c(BS, car, active, TX)

Here the real trip observed is a taxi from column name "mode". Then I need to change to value in "chioce" column 0 at row 1 and 1 at row 4 based on the "mainmode" column information where BS= BUS, car =car, active= walk, TX = taxi.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you expect for output?

Comment: The expected output will be, choice column becomes choice =c(0, 0, 0, 1). Because TX is in row 4 in mainmode variable.

Comment: You probably need to explain more. What is the logic to change values in `choice` ?

Comment: In this dataset, the first column indicates the observed travel mode for a passenger, the second column is the dummy variable where 1 = observed, 0 = not observed, and third column is the supporting variable for the second column. I need to replace the value of second column (i.e, choice) 0 by 1 where the value of first and third column matching. In this case column 3 has TX (i.e taxi) in row 4 which is matching with column 1. That's why in "choice" I need to replace 0 in row 4 by 1 and 1 in row 1 by 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mode` and `mainmode` do not have the same terms so it is not possible to compare them. Change either `mode` or `mainmode` and then it is easy to compare them directly.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   mutate(mainmode = recode(mainmode, 'BS' = 'BUS', 'car' = 'car', 
                            'active' = 'walk', 'TX' = 'taxi'), 
          choice = as.integer(mode == mainmode))


#  mode choice mainmode
#1 taxi      0      BUS
#2 taxi      0      car
#3 taxi      0     walk
#4 taxi      1     taxi
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(mode=c("taxi", "taxi", "taxi", "taxi"), choice = c(1, 0, 0, 0),
           mainmode = c("BS", "car", "active", "TX"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ronak. You are excellent ! Your approach is 100% correct to me based on what I expected from this query. Take care dear. I hope we will meet in future as well.

Comment: @ Ronak Shah, I have one more query here.  If there is no "TX"  in "mainmode" in given dataset then I would like to remain the same values in choice as it is in dataset. How do perform this query when we have both cases in dataset (that mean TX is present or absent in mainmode in dataset). Thanks in advance.

Comment: So do you mean that first value would remain as 0 since it is not "TX" ? In that case, you can use `df %>%
  mutate(mainmode = recode(mainmode, 'BS' = 'BUS', 'car' = 'car', 
                           'active' = 'walk', 'TX' = 'taxi'), 
         choice = ifelse(mainmode != 'taxi', choice, as.integer(mode == mainmode)))`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in data frame `df`, you need to create a lookup table and then look up the values to convert from your mainmode to mode. Then match on mode.

```
modelookup=data.frame(mode=c("bus","car","walk","taxi"),main=c("BS","car","active","TX"))
df$lookup = modelookup$mode[match(df$mainmode, modelookup$main)]
df$choice = as.numeric(df$mode==df$lookup)
```

Comment: @ F Trias: My main objective is to replace the value of second column (i.e, choice) 0 by 1 where the value of first and third column matching. In this case column 3 has TX (i.e taxi) in row 4 which is matching with column 1 value. That's why in "choice" I need to replace 0 in row 4 by 1 and 1 in row 1 by 0.

Comment: Make this query more simple: Given data=data.frame(mode=c("taxi","taxi","taxi","taxi"),choice = c(1,0, 0,0),mainmode=c("BS","car","active","TX")); Target output = data.frame(mode=c("taxi","taxi","taxi","taxi"),choice = c(0,0, 0,1),mainmode=c("BS","car","active","TX")). How do I get this target output from the given data using R scripts or function?

Comment: That's what the last line does. It sets choice to c(0,0,0,1). Why don't you show us the original dataframe by using `dput` as in `dput(df)` so we can see what you're working with?

Comment: Your data is strings, not factors. So you need to convert the match: `df$choice = as.numeric(df$mode==as.character(df$lookup))`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, mainmode := recode(mainmode, 'BS' = 'BUS', 
                  'car' = 'car', 
                           'active' = 'walk', 'TX' = 'taxi')][, choice := +(mode == mainmode)]
df
#   mode choice mainmode
#1: taxi      0      BUS
#2: taxi      0      car
#3: taxi      0     walk
#4: taxi      1     taxi
```

---

or in `base R`, this can be done with a named vector

```
df$mainmode <- setNames(c('BUS', 'car', 'walk', 'taxi'), 
           c('BS', 'car', 'active', 'TX'))[as.character(df$mainmode)]
df$choice <- +(df$mode == df$mainmode)
```

data

```
df <- data.frame(mode=c("taxi", "taxi", "taxi", "taxi"), choice = c(1, 0, 0, 0),
       mainmode = c("BS", "car", "active", "TX"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Akrun. Your approach is also excellent which meet my exception from this query. Take care and hope to catch up with future query in R.